# create a CCSprite from part of a CCSprite/CCSpriteFrame/CCSpriteBatchNode

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

can you create a new CCSprite from a part of a CCSprite within a CCSpriteBatchNode?

For a long time, I've used SpriteFrameCache and BatchNode without a 100% understanding of the two, in particular how they relate to the textureCache. I could use some clear advice to accomplish the following:

Currently, I load a texture atlas into CCSpriteBatchNode and the frame list into the CCSpriteFrameCache and generate a sprite in what I think is basic standard fasion

```
CCSpriteBatchNode *batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"textureAtlasImage.png"];
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"textureAtlasFrames.plist"];

CCSprite * gameObject = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"gameObject.png"];
[self addChild:batchNode];
[batchNodeaddChild:gameObject];
```

For the sake of simplicity with the question, What I'd like to do is divide gameObject into 4 pieces programatically (rather than divide the original image into four pieces and adding each into the textureAtlasImage.png individually).

From reading, I'm thinking something like:

```
CCSpriteFrame * gameObjectFrame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"textureAtlasFrames.plist"];
CCTexture2D * gameObjectIndividualTexture = [[gameObjectFrame] texture];
CCSpriteFrame * gameObjectPartFrame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:gameObjectIndividualTexture offset: rectInPixels: ] ;
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache]  addSpriteFrame:gameObjectPartFrame name:@"gameObjectPart1"];
```

But my questions then are:
Is this already in the batchNode? If not, how do I actually create the sprite out of the gameObjectPart1 using batchNodes?
Is it wasteful to add another spriteframe to the cache that duplicates data elsewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to adjust the texture rect after creating the sprite. Create four sprites using the same sprite frame, then set each sprite's texture rect to one of the 4 smaller regions you want them to use.

Use the `sprite.textureRect` property to get the CGRect with the original size and change the size respectively origin. For example the lower left rectangle can be created by setting textureRect to the same rect but with size.width and size.height halved.

Comment: thanks steffen, will try. when adding to the sprite batch node, do i just need to add one version of the sprite prior to adjusting the textureRect or each individual one after adjustment?

Comment: You'll need 4 sprites. And in case the above doesn't work (not sure if batch node uses textureRect or the sprite frame) you can create custom sprite frames and adjust their rectangles. You don't need to cache those as they'll be retained by the sprites using the frames.